# Connecting buttons from one panel class to data from another

Tags: java, swing

First of all hi all, thanks for the help. I have a problem creating a simple program with java swing using a specific setup of classes. I would be able to make it work using a simpler setup, but for my assignment it needs to be done this way. Anyway to the code:

this is the basic jframe with instances of classes. Really simple, not much here.

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame {

private FormPanel   fPanel;
DonjiBotuniPanel    dbtnPanel;

public MainFrame() {

    super("Enrollment app");
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setSize(400, 300);
    setMinimumSize(new Dimension(400, 300));
    // setResizable(false);
    createComposition();
    add(fPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(dbtnPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

}

private void createComposition() {
    fPanel = new FormPanel();
    dbtnPanel = new DonjiBotuniPanel();

}

}
```

Then we have the first panel class with some layout and component creation methods and a few getters for field data:

```
public class FormPanel extends JPanel {

private JLabel                          fNameLbl;
private JLabel                          lNameLbl;
private JLabel                          depLbl;
private JLabel                          idLbl;
private JTextField                      fNameTxt;
private JTextField                      lNameTxt;
private JTextField                      idTxt;
private JComboBox<String>               depCombo;
private JRadioButton                    croCitzn;
private JRadioButton                    forCitzn;
private DefaultComboBoxModel<String>    dcBoxModel;
private ButtonGroup                     radGrp;

public FormPanel() {

    setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    createComposition();
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

    gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
    // gbc.weighty = 1;
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
    add(fNameLbl, gbc);

    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    add(lNameLbl, gbc);

    gbc.gridx = 2;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    add(depLbl, gbc);

    // gbc.weighty = 0;
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    add(fNameTxt, gbc);

    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    add(lNameTxt, gbc);

    gbc.gridx = 2;
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    add(depCombo, gbc);

    gbc.insets = new Insets(20, 0, 0, 0);
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 3;
    add(idLbl, gbc);

    gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 4;
    add(idTxt, gbc);

    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.gridy = 4;
    add(croCitzn, gbc);

    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.gridy = 5;
    add(forCitzn, gbc);
    setBorders();

}

private void setBorders() {

    Border inner = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("user info:");
    Border outer = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5);

    setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(outer, inner));
}

private void createComposition() {
    fNameLbl = new JLabel("First name: ");
    fNameTxt = new JTextField(5);
    lNameLbl = new JLabel("Last name: ");
    lNameTxt = new JTextField(5);
    depLbl = new JLabel("Department");
    idLbl = new JLabel("Unique id: ");
    idTxt = new JTextField(5);
    createComboModel();
    depCombo = new JComboBox<>(dcBoxModel);
    radGrp = new ButtonGroup();
    croCitzn = new JRadioButton("CRO citizenship");
    forCitzn = new JRadioButton("Foreign citizenship");
    radGrp.add(croCitzn);
    radGrp.add(forCitzn);
    croCitzn.setSelected(true);

}

private void createComboModel() {
    dcBoxModel = new DefaultComboBoxModel<>();
    dcBoxModel.addElement("Informatika");
    dcBoxModel.addElement("Kultura");
    dcBoxModel.addElement("Turizam");
    dcBoxModel.addElement("Filozofija");
    dcBoxModel.addElement("Jezik");
}



public String getfNameTxt() {
    return fNameTxt.getText();
}

public String getlNameTxt() {
    return lNameTxt.getText();
}

public String getIdTxt() {
    return idTxt.getText();
}


}
```

And finally a panel class for three buttons that go below:

```
public class DonjiBotuniPanel extends JPanel {

private JButton sndDta;
private JButton cncl;
private JButton src;
private JPanel  contBtn;
private JPanel  contBtn2;

public DonjiBotuniPanel() {
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    createComposition();

    add(contBtn, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
    add(contBtn2, BorderLayout.LINE_START);

}

private void createComposition() {
    sndDta = new JButton("Send data");
    cncl = new JButton("Cancel");
    src = new JButton("Search");
    contBtn = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));
    contBtn.add(src);
    contBtn2 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
    contBtn2.add(sndDta);
    contBtn2.add(cncl);
}

}
```

And now the trouble starts. I cant for the life of me connect buttons from DonjiBotuniPanel with data from FormPanel. I know i could set up classes differently using inner/outer classes in a single java file and i would be able to make it work that way. But i cant make it work this way. I understand there needs to be a link between them, maybe a controller of some sort, and i tried a lot of different things, but i cant quite seem to get it.

So to simplify if you dont want to read through all the code (most of it is just component creation and layouts anyway). I have three classes in three java files. One is the MainFrame and in it i create instances of the second two classes - FormPanel which has all the JTextFields (data) in its own java file and DonjiBotuniPanel which has three buttons. Since i cant really create a new instance of FormPanel(data) in DonjiBotuniPanel i cant extract data from FormPanel to manipulate using buttons from DonjiBotuniPanel.

Any help would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just make a new class for example DataTransferClass and init that class in MainFrame.
DonjiBotuniPanel and FormPanel takes this object as their constructor parameter. Add necessary data fields in DataTransferClass and set these fields' values in FormPanel and get them in DonjiBotuniPanel. Make changes in MainFrame class createComposition methos like below:

MainFrame:

```
private void createComposition() {
    dataTransferClass = new DataTransferClass();
    fPanel = new FormPanel(dataTransferClass);
    dbtnPanel = new DonjiBotuniPanel(dataTransferClass);
}
```

Make necessary changes in other classes.

Comment: Thanks, i will zry thus as soon as i get home

Comment: Ok, the problem with this is as follows. When i start the program, the fields are blank. If i use setters from the new DataTransferClass in FormPanel it is done at the start of running the program. The DonjiBotuniPanel with buttons has the ActionListener. So again, i would need the button to set values in DataTransferClass with data from FormPanel, which i cant get in DonjiBotuniPanel.

Comment: But you got me on the right track! thanks so much! I used fPanel as DonjiBotuniPanel constructor parameter and went from there. It works how i want it to now.

Comment: You are welcome @Ink22. If it helped to solve your problem you can accept answer ;)